# WCF returning nil value and actual value in Data Contract

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service that is calling another WCF service to get some information from one of our systems and it appears that the values being returned contained some nil values. However, on looking at the XML that was returned, it appeared that the returned values contain two entries for the same DataMamber, one with a nil value and one with the actual value i was expecting eg,

I see something similar to the following in the  of the XML returned where the DataMembers have nil values:

```
<b:AccountNumber i:nil="true" />
<b:Created>0001-01-01T00:00:00</b:Created>
<b:CreatedBy i:nil="true" />
<b:EmailAddress i:nil="true" />
<b:GivenNames i:nil="true" />
```

and then in the same document but further down, I see the following where the same Data Members have the values I expect:

```
<b:Id>16996172</b:Id>
<b:Created>2007-07-16T16:32:48.789755</b:Created>
<b:CreatedBy>SYSTEM</b:CreatedBy>
<b:RowStatus>None</b:RowStatus>
<b:AccountNumber>1234567</b:AccountNumber>
<b:EmailAddress>email@test.com.au</b:EmailAddress>
<b:GivenNames>TEST NAME</b:GivenNames>
```

Not all the DataMembers that are being returned are duplicated like this and it seems that a few values are returned with nil then all of the correct values are returned.

Has anyone seen something like this before or could hazard a guess as to what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by the WSDL and Data Contracts not matching the web services themselves.

Running svcutil.exe against the web services that were running and not the WSDL files provided fixed the problem.